# how to get column name in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

this is phpmyadmin table : user_test_detail 
[image: this is phpmyadmin table : user_test_detail]

I want result like below

```
(
[1] => option_a
[2] => option_d
[3] => option_e
[4] => option_d
)
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: 1,2,3,4 is question_id and option_a, option_d, option_e, option_d are values. It shows where value is 1 that field name will come in front of question_id

Comment: Is this all the columns in table `user_test_detail`?

Comment: yes, column name want to get in values

Answer (score 1):

GET IT form information schema

```
mysql> SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME="TEST";
+-------------+
| COLUMN_NAME |
+-------------+
| user_id     |
| NAME        |
| value       |
+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
select 
    case
        when option_a = '1' then `option_a`
        when option_b = '1' then `option_b`
        when option_c = '1' then `option_c`
        when option_d = '1' then `option_d`
        when option_e = '1' then `option_e`
    end as colName
from user_test_detail
order by question_id
```

This is only for this 5 columns in table `user_test_detail`, and if you will change this table's structure in the future, you have to use dynamic sql.

***Edited:***

```
select 
    max(case when question_id = 1 then colName end) as `1`,
    max(case when question_id = 2 then colName end) as `2`,
    max(case when question_id = 3 then colName end) as `3`,
    max(case when question_id = 4 then colName end) as `4`
from (
    select 
        case
            when option_a = '1' then `option_a`
            when option_b = '1' then `option_b`
            when option_c = '1' then `option_c`
            when option_d = '1' then `option_d`
            when option_e = '1' then `option_e`
        end as colName,
        question_id
    from user_test_detail
    order by question_id
) t
-- group by question_id
```

Comment: you can get it form information schema no need to write complex query

Comment: @MaheshMadushanka Did you realize he did not want all the columns in table, but columns with value is 1 and order by `question_id`?

Comment: yes aggred it was not mention in the initial question

Comment: hello 10086, not getting field name in colName. Right now colName value is 1 as per 4 question.

Comment: @TerryBabuSamuel What do you mean about 'not working'?

Comment: 1,2,3,4 is as a column name and 1 value is as per question_id and others are NULL, I want question_id and in option as per 1 (field name)